# running GAE GQL in Datastore Viewer in development

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have seen many references to using GQL in the "GAE Datastore viewer" but I just cant find a place to do that...

I am using the `GAE JAVA SDK v1.8.8` and accessing the Data Store viewer via `http://localhost:8899/_ah/admin/datastore`.

Was this option removed? or should I somehow enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Using GQL is not part of the local development server. It is available in the live App Engine console for your application.

The development web server includes a Datastore Viewer (/_ah/admin/datastore) via which you can *only* browse the local datastore.

Comment: great, so I can debug a production environment but not the development environment... real smart...